# grok pattern works in debugger but not in logstash

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a grok pattern that works in [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), but I can't get it to work in logstash. In particular, it's the regex that fails. Basically, I want to match a string in the "source" field

"source" field I want to filter:

```
/var/log/containers/my-container-190662183-f6wlm_logging_logstash-testing-10897cc1fe13d419f73b8c7929377a1f98366a648e85e71163c4fdaac278e256.log
```

Grok filter:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "path" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{CONTAINERAPP:container}*" }
    patterns_dir => ["/root/patterns"]
  }
}
```

Pattern:

```
CONTAINERAPP .+(?=-\d)
```

Note that I'm not trying to parse log lines here, just assign a field to a matched pattern. Other regexes produce the "container" field, just not quite the string that I need.

My guess is that the Oniguruma syntax does not support this particular regex, but if that's the case, why does the grok debugger say it's OK?

Comment: by this .+(?=-\d) you say: one or more of something with following one digit or tire, probably you need add a plus:  .+(?=-\d)+

Comment: @volkinc: No need to quantify a zero-width assertion that consumes no text. The [regex is fine](https://regex101.com/r/TqNmLM/1). I think the problem is how the fields are defined, try `"%{GREEDYDATA:path}/%{CONTAINERAPP:container}"`